# STM32F205 - can i use a timer to generate a low pulse of specified length

Tags: pwm, c, arm, stm32, stm32f2

I want a pin to be high by default and then generate two 125-250 µs pulses with 0.1 µs resolution using a command. I was thinking about using TIM1 in one-pulse mode but I don't see a way to invert the logic. And can two channels of a single timer be used in one-pulse mode simultaneously?

Comment: Have you RTFM'd yet?

Comment: Yes. The solution is CHxN - negative output channels.

Answer (score 1):

Without going into the timer docs, I can say it's certainly possible if you invert the output with a NOT gate or a transistor!